# Is there an option to create a vector that contains functions with different return types?

Tags: c++, vector, std-variant

I have the following vectors

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::function<std::string(const PlayerFRDb&)>>> stringExtractors = {
    {" TEAM ", extractTeam},
    {" NAME ", extractName},
    {" TYPE ", extractProperty4},
};

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::function<int(const PlayerFRDb&)>>> intExtractors = {
    {" WS ", extractProperty0},
    {" LS ", extractProperty1},
    {" W ", extractProperty2},
    {" L ", extractProperty3},
};

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::function<char(const PlayerFRDb&)>>> charExtractors = {
    {" WAY ", extractProperty5},
};

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::function<double(const PlayerFRDb&)>>> doubleExtractors = {
    {" LINE ", extractProperty6},
};
```

To make it easier to work with these functions, I want to lump them into one vector, but the problem is that they return different types.

I tried using std::variant, but I can't initialize the vector, because the compiler prints out: "**no instance of constructor matches the argument list argument types are ({...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...})** "

```
using FuncVariant = std::variant<
    std::function<std::string(const PlayerFRDb&)>,
    std::function<int(const PlayerFRDb&)>,
    std::function<double(const PlayerFRDb&)>
>;

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, FuncVariant>> extractors = {
    {" TEAM ", extractTeam},
    {" NAME ", extractName},
    {" TYPE ", extractProperty4},
    {" WS ", extractProperty0},
    {" LS ", extractProperty1},
    {" W ", extractProperty2},
    {" L ", extractProperty3},
    {" LINE ", extractProperty6},
};
```

Is there an option to create a vector that contains functions with different return types?

Comment: _"To make it easier to work with these functions, I want to lump them into one vector"_ - How is that easier?

Comment: *"To make it easier to work with these functions, I want to lump them into one vector"* - are you really sure that will make anything easier? You will then have to somehow handle how to work with each different type of function when accessing the elements of the vector

Comment: In another way, how do you expect/want to use element of the vector afterward?

Comment: I want to pass these functions as arguments to statistical functions, this would make easier to create more combined statistics. As if I wanted, for example to create different combinations of class members. I would have to create n! extractors.

Comment: @konradtrubilo When you get a value of unknown type in return, what will you do with it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As a side note, an request to remove types are almost always premised on fundamental misunderstandings of how strongly typed languages work, either because you learnt another language with weak typing or you haven't thought through how the entire program is supposed to be written.

Comment: Sidenote: Wouldn't the vectors be better as maps of some sort?

Comment: how will you call the funciotns? What will you do with the return type?

Comment: `std::string team = std::get<std::function<std::string(const PlayerFRDb&)>(extractors[0].second)(player);`? Doesn't seem very convenient even if you add shorthand aliases for the function types. (Like e.g. `std::string team = std::get<string_extractor>(extractors[0].second)(player);`).

Comment: @molbdnilo I want to create a std::tuple<..> from these functions to make summary statistics based on various members.

Comment: @konradtrubilo why not make a std::tuple of functions in that case?

Comment: @konradtrubilo If you'd also shown the intended usage, you could have gotten something more suited for your needs.

Comment: @Caleth Well in general i created a function that has a parameter std::function<std::tuple<Ts...>>(player), so that's why I want to create a vector of functions with different types -> create function<std::tuple<decltype(extractors[i].sec),...> and then send it to function. It may be wrong but i dont know of a better solution.

Comment: `decltype(extractors[i].sec)` is always going to be the same type, so that doesn't help

Comment: I know, I shortened it. Now I have to find a solution how to extract type from the variant, but thanks a lot for suggesting this idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to help the compiler deduce the template arguments you can wrap all functions with `std::function{}`.

```
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int foo(void) {return 0;}
char bar(void) {return '0';}

using FuncVariant = std::variant<std::function<int()>,std::function<char()>>;
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, FuncVariant>> vec{
        {"TEAM", std::function{bar}},
        {"W", std::function{foo}}
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than having the variant over the function type, you can have the function type return a variant.

```
using FuncVariant = std::function<std::variant<std::string, int, double>(const PlayerFRDb&)>;

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, FuncVariant>> extractors = {
    {" TEAM ", extractTeam},
    {" NAME ", extractName},
    {" TYPE ", extractProperty4},
    {" WS ", extractProperty0},
    {" LS ", extractProperty1},
    {" W ", extractProperty2},
    {" L ", extractProperty3},
    {" LINE ", extractProperty6},
};
```